# High temperature high voltage electrical insulation under water

Tags: insulation

I am mechanical engineer, and it is my hobby to make some thing new from broken and expired machines.

I found a broken electrical kettle, and I want to make a water heater from it by using its coil. The coil is already insulated, according to design it is to hang it in water. 
Now I need to insulate the connection of wires for the coil.

Please I need help to find insulation material, which can withstand High temperature of the coil, also give it electrical insulation under water. And also from where I can get it easily.

Thanks

Comment: you may perhaps get flagged as this could be seen as a repair question. We have no clue how that coil looks like, so we need pictures an some drawings, how your water heater should look like. In general I do not recommend modifications involving line voltage and water. You will very likely electrocute yourself for having saved a handful of bucks.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find it easily, for a kettle element.

Things like araldite and heatshrink plastic tube will tolerate 100C (just), but unfortunately the inside business part of a kettle element runs far hotter than that, only cooling down to nearly 100C where it contacts the water.

If you look at immersion elements, you will find a continuous metal tube extends out of the water, either extended from the same element tube, or welded to it, with ceramic insulator inside.

I'm not saying a suitable waterproof and heat resistant glue or plastic doesn't exist, just that it won't be as easy to find as looking in a normal electronics catalogue.